# Is it ok to post Technical Service Bulletins on MVM&R?

Tags: discussion, meta

I personally had a problem with my car about a year ago, and found a Technical Service Bulletin (TSB) from the manufacturer regarding the issue. I ended up using the TSB to get a dealer to fix the problem for cheap. Is it ok to post TSB numbers / information from TSBs in your questions/answers on MVM&R?

Comment: Why would this question even come up? It seems obvious to me that it is absolutely relevant. Did you run into some policy prohibiting similar information on other SE sites?

Comment: 1) I'm quite new to the world of doing my own work on cars. 2) In my limited dealings with TSBs, car manufacturers and dealerships have stated that the documents are for internal use only (whether that is true or not, I do not know). 3) The fact that anything but the titles of TSBs are very hard to find online (without paid subscription services) would, in my mind, makes it plausible that #2 is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word Yes, if they are related to the question.

Comment: Absolutely: that's critical information.